# How to validate fields from a dataservice in DSS?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I'm making a data service but in a int field I need to validate that is not greater than 10 and less than 0.

Comment: Please add some details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are creating the field you can add the type of validation you decide, selecting the option to add validation, you need to select the option "Long Range Validation" and define minimum and maximum value that you want.

An example query where I use this validation, by default the minimum value is 0 so it is omitted.

```
   <query id="1" useConfig="DS_FARMACY">
        <sql>call getEmployeeById(?)</sql>
        <result element="Employees" rowName="Employe">
            <element column="id" name="Id" xsdType="integer"/>
            <element column="Desc" name="Description" xsdType="string"/>
        </result>
        <param name="Id" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="INTEGER" type="IN">
            <validateLongRange maximum="10"/>
        </param>
    </query>
```

Review the WSO2 documentation where each option is specified to validate fields
http://wso2.com/project/data-services/2.6.3/docs/validation.html

Answer (score 3):

Validators are added to individual input mappings in a query. Input validation allows data services to validate the input parameters in a request and stop the execution of the request if the input doesn’t meet required criteria. WSO2 Data Service Server provides a set of built-in validators for some of the most common use cases. It also provides an extension mechanism to write custom validators.

In this case you need select Long Range Validator to validate if an integer value is in the specified range. The validator requires a minimum and a maximum value to set the range. For example:

[image: example]